# MAMPでドメイン形式を作って新しく作成したフォルダへアクセスするとNot foundになる。

Tags: mamp

Mampでのローカル環境について質問させてください。

先日までは普通に使用できていたのですが、新規で作成したファイルへのアクセスがすべてNot Foundとなってしまい困っています。

当方環境：Mac
参考にした環境構築方法：http://do-wp.com/virtual-hosts-on-mamp/
症状：新規に作成したフォルダへアクセスするとすべてNot Foundになる。
すでに作成していたローカルドメインには繋がる。

apache_error.logを調べて見たところ
[Tue Aug 28 17:11:25 2018] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hogehoge\xe2\x80\x9d
のように表示されています

また、気になる点としては localhostにアクセスすると、 testと命名してるドメインサーバーが表示され
localhostが表示されなくなっています。（testというドメイン・サーバーには繋がる）

vhost、hostsファイルは打ち間違いがないか確認済み
mampの再起動も試しましたが改善しません。
hogehogeの中身にはWordpressなどは入っておらず、hosts直下にwordpressの環境を構築などはしておりません。
困っておりますので、どなたかアドバイスいただけると助かります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

vhostのDocument rootの設定を見直してください。
たぶん、ダブルクオートが全角になっています。